# Сортировка матрицы

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, матрицы

Дана матрица n * m , нужно отсортировать и вывести колонками от самого маленького к самому большому, у меня не выходит сделать, смотреть ниже.

Мой код:

```
n , m = map(int,input().split())
matrix = [list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(n)]
matrix_copy = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
li = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        li.append(matrix[i][j])
li.sort()
k = -1
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        k +=1
        matrix_copy[i][j] = li[k]

x = (list(zip(*matrix_copy)))

for i in x:
    print(*i)
```

Вход: n - количество строк, m- количество колонок, потом вводим матрицу нужного размера.

Как работает у меня:

```
input:

3 3
4 1 3
2 5 7
9 8 6

output:

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

input:
1 3
4 2 1
output:
1
2
4

input:
3 1
9
7
8

output:

7 8 9
```

Как должно быть:

```
input0:

3 3
4 1 3
2 5 7
9 8 6

output0:

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

input1:
1 3
4 2 1

output1:
1 2 4

input2:
3 1
9
7
8
output2:
7
8
9
```

Comment: Как долго быть понятно. А как выводится? И в каком виде происходит ввод?

Comment: попробую в коменте написать , ввод : 1 3 *энтер*
4 2 1 , вместо 1 2 4 выводиться 1 энтер, 2 энтер, 4

Comment: @Эникейщик написан же инпут ниже , в чем проблема? n * m матрица , n и m в инпуте первые строки , дальше матрица которую нужно отсортировать.

Comment: Комментарии не являтся частью вопроса, правте сам вопрос.

Comment: @Danis ну так открой вопрос , алло, сам сказал второй удалить, чтобы дубликата не было

Comment: надо чтобы ещё четыре человека проголосовали за открытие, либо один модератор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любое разумное решение будет следовать образцу: перевести матрицу в список, упорядочить список, расставить числа из списка в элементы матрицы. Но на Питоне есть пара трюков которые облегчают задачу.

Собрать матрицу можно в одну строку. Получится не список, а генератор:

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(matrix)
```

Функция `sorted` принимает вход в том числе и генераторы, возвращает список.

Собрать матрицу из списка тоже можно в одну строку с помощью слайсов:

```
[lst[i::n] for i in range(n)]
```

Код целиком:

```
import itertools


def sorted_by_columns(matrix):
    n = len(matrix)
    lst = sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable(matrix))
    return [lst[i::n] for i in range(n)]


def print_matrix(matrix):
    for r in matrix:
        print(*r)


def check(matrix):
    print('-' * 10)
    print_matrix(matrix)
    print('-')
    print_matrix(sorted_by_columns(matrix))
    print('-' * 10)


check([
    [4, 1, 3],
    [2, 5, 7],
    [9, 8, 6]
])
check([
    [4, 2, 1]
])
check([
    [9],
    [7],
    [8]
])
```

Результаты:

```
----------
4 1 3
2 5 7
9 8 6
-
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
----------
----------
4 2 1
-
1 2 4
----------
----------
9
7
8
-
7
8
9
----------
```

Comment: Спасибо! Благодаря вашему решению получилось уместить задачу в 6 строк, я пытался решить слайсами , но у меня почему-то не выходило. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 4):

Во второй части вашей программы (и частично и в первой) вы усложняете себе жизнь.

```
n, m = map(int,input().split())
matrix = [list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(n)]
li = []
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        li.append(matrix[i][j])
li.sort()

# ------- дотуда (почти) ваш код, теперь мой --------

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        print(li[n * j + i], end=" ")
    print()
```

`n * j + i` просто индекс `i`-той строки и `j`-того столбца в вашем списке `li`.

Comment: Не работает так , как нужно. Вы сами пробовали вставить инпуты , которые в описании вопроса и проверить?

Comment: @Michaelan, ой, вы прав. Вы хотели по столбцам, я сделал по строкам. — Я исправил мой ответ, правка была простая — вместо `[m * i + j]` дал `[n * j + i]` (поменял `m`↔`n`, `i`↔`j`).